# Calculating Distance Range

Tags: java, android, android-activity, gps, parse-platform

I am able to retrieve user latitude and longitude, and hence have their location coordinate through GPS.
For instance lets say I have latitude 67, and longitude -25, and lets say I wanted limit the search to 100km, would it be like +- 20 current latitude, and +- 10 current longitude?

If you need any clarification, let me know.
Thanks in advance

Comment: That's more of a math question than a programming one.

Comment: Converting decimal degrees coords to kilometers is not constant, I suggest using JTS to perform a buffer operation, or store your data in something like PostGIS so you can store it as geometry and perform spatial queries... depending on your goal

Comment: Thanks for your responses. The user latitude and longitude information is recorded directly into Parse so I have that information. I agree this is more of a mathematical question.

Comment: How about if I wanted to calculate the distance between two points if the distance falls within that specified range, than it would execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse makes this very easy. They have built in function called: [`withinKilometers:`](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#withinKilometers), [`withinMiles:`](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#withinMiles), and [`withinRadians:`](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#withinRadians). The following query parameter will return all the rows where "location" is within 100 kilometers of the user's current location. Since you've already calculated the user's latitude and longitude, you can create a [`PFGeoPoint`](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFGeoPoint.html) using those values.

**Swift Syntax**

```
let userLocation = PFGeoPoint(latitude: userLatitude, longitude: userLongitude)
query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint:userLocation, withinKilometers: 100)
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I believe the android equivalent is         query.whereWithinKilometers("location", ParseGeoPoint point, double maxDistance); For the point, I, I have managed to store the user latitude and longitude through GPS, so not sure what would the point be reference to or the "location" since there no column under my parse that has "location"

Comment: Updated my answer @user3907211 As for your "location" column, it's whatever column you're comparing the PFGeoPoint to. Note: You shouldn't save the user's latitude and longitude to Parse. Instead save a PFGeoPoint.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am wondering wouldn't using GPS through parse drastically increase the amount of request, and hence increase the fee. Lets say I have 2000 users who spent an average of 30minute on the application per day, wouldn't that be more than 30 request per second because of constantly asking the application for its current location

Comment: I'm not sure without knowing more about your project. Why would you need to ask Parse for your current location? Just use the phone's GPS.